# $_FILES empty when upload multiple files with FormData from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, multipartform-data

The problem is that when I try to upload a single file the server gets the request and I see that $ _FILES actually contains the uploaded file.

On the other hand, when I try to upload more files, the request comes with $ _FILES completely empty.

```html
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images-input-file" accept="image/jpeg" multiple="multiple" hidden />
```

```js
//In this case '$(this)' is the file input
var files = $(this)[0].files;

//Append data to Form Data
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   formData.append("file-" + i, files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/server/fnc/upload-images",
   data: formData,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
   },
});
```

Comment: Your ajax seems fine to me, maybe the issue is somewhere else. Check the network tab of development tools to see if the request is occurring as you expect. Post your server code, the issue could be there.

Comment: My server code is a simple print_r($_FILES);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to do this is to use the form submit like this:

```
$("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/server/fnc/upload-images",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }           
    });
}));
```

else can you try this to test:

```
var formData = new FormData();
$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file', file);
});
```